# Can $f(z)=1/z$ exist at the origin in $|z|=1$?

Tags: complex-analysis

I have the simple complex function $f(z)=1/z$, defined on $\gamma=|z|=1$. In order for it to be holomorphic, and thus entire, it has to be differentiable in |z|. In order to prove that it is entire I used the derivative formula

$df(z)/dz=\lim_{\Delta z\longrightarrow 0}=\frac{z_0+\Delta z-z_0}{\Delta z}$ and ended up with :

\begin{equation}
f'(z)=\frac{z_0}{z_0}-1
\end{equation}

So it looks to me that at any point inside the unit circle, it gives a derivative of zero, so the function is entire. But at the origin, I get $\frac{0}{0}$. So is this function entire when it does not exist at the origin but elsewhere inside the unit circle?

Comment: I’m not sure how you’re defining $f$ inside the unit circle if it’s only defined on the outside, but the derivative of $1/z$ is $-1/z^2$. Your limit calculation doesn’t look sensible to me.

Comment: Thanks, I will revise

Comment: The phrasing of this question is unclear. How can the function $f$ be entire if it's only defined on the unit circle? Did you mean to ask for an entire function $g$ whose restriction to the unit circle equals $f$?

Comment: Yes, precisely.

Comment: @Eric it was easy to differentiate it by treating z as a real variable, but does that always work?

Comment: If that's what you're asking, your computation makes no sense. What would $df/dz$ mean for a function that's only defined on the unit circle? And of course $g(z)=1/z$ is not entire, since it has a pole at the origin, so that function does not solve the problem (if that's what you're suggesting). In fact there is no entire function $g$ which agrees with $1/z$ on the unit circle; see here for some hints: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula#Theorem.

Comment: Great, thanks for this. I have revised the solution to include the correct derivative. Since holomorphism is based on differentiability, and that is the core for "entireness", then it can easily be proven that , as you say, f(z)=1/z is not entire within $|z|=1.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose, for contradiction, that there exists $g(z)$ entire holomorphic such that $g$ restricted to the unit circle is $\frac{1}{z}$. Then, by Cauchy integral formula:
$$ 
g(0) = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{\partial D_1(0)} g(z) \mathrm{d}z = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{\partial D_1(0)} \frac{1}{z} \mathrm{d}z = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{1}{e^{i\theta}} (i e^{i \theta})\mathrm{d}\theta = 1
$$ On the other hand, since $g$ is holomorphic everywhere, the integral of $g(z)$ over any closed loop should yield zero, so in particular $\int_{\partial D_1(0)}g(z)\mathrm{d}z = 0$, which contradicts the equation above. Therefore, no such $g$ exists.